# Setter but no getter for referenced attribute with Mongoid+ActiveModel

Tags: mongoid, activemodel

I have an Invoice (belongs_to :contact) and a Contact (has_many :invoices).
In a new invoice form I want to reference which contact it belongs to. For that purpose, the following field:

```
<input name='invoice[contact]' type='text'>
```

Which works when I write the contact's id. No problems there. However, I want it to work with the contact's *name*. So I added the following callback in *Invoice*:

```
before_save do |invoice|
  invoice.contact = Contact.find_by(name: invoice.contact)
end
```

However, *invoice.contact* turns out to be nil (despite the input field not being empty) which throws an error as there's no contact with name: nil.

The following work:

```
before_save do |invoice|
  invoice.contact = Contact.find_by(name: 'some name')
end
```

and

```
before_save do |invoice|
  invoice.contact = Contact.find('52a233b585c4f0fa7d000001')
end
```

This leads me to believe that there's a setter for invoice.contact but not a getter.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have better luck if you use a virtual attribute for the name, otherwise I think you'll run into problems when someone tries to treat a name like `'Bob Dobbs'` as an ObjectId. Something like this in your form:

```
<input name='invoice[contact_name]' type='text'>
```

and then in your Mongoid model:

```
attr_reader :contact_name
attr_accessible :contact_name
before_save do |invoice|
  invoice.contact = Contact.find_by(name: invoice.contact_name)
end
```

That should get you the contact name in `invoice_contact_name` as a String and nothing will try to interpret it as anything other than a string.

I'd probably drop the `before_save` hook and move the `Contact.find_by` into a `before_validation` instead, then you can validate that you have a `contact_id` and have a chance to detect a bad `contact_name`:

```
attr_reader :contact_name
attr_accessible :contact_name
before_validation :lookup_contact_name
validate_presence_of :contact_id

def lookup_contact_name
  # Some sort of `contact_name` cleanup might be a good idea in here too.
  self.contact = Contact.find_by(name: contact_name)
end
```

Comment: invoice.contact_name still returns nil despite the form now having a name: 'invoice[contact_name]' field and being filled in.It's strange because I have things like:

    invoice.paid_with = nil unless invoice.paid

and don't give that error. attr_reader and attr_accessible don't seem to do anything.

Comment: After trying some permutations:
invoice.contact and invoice[:contact] return nil no matter what.
invoice[:contact_name] works and doesn't require an attr_anything.
With that small modification your solution does the trick but I'm still wondering why those getter methods don't work no matter how many attr readers and attr accessibles there are.

Comment: Gotcha: A field with name='invoice[contact_name]' appears to be understood by mongoid as a dynamic attribute, so an invoice ends up with an invoice name (the id of the contact, assigned by the callback) and an invoice contact name (despite not being such field in the model) among its other attributes.

Comment: The second version should work unless I'm missing something obvious (wouldn't be the first time).